# contact form 7 database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, contact-form-7

newbie question. I mange to create a database for cf7 to save all the submission. everything work fine but I`m not getting the desire results:

this is what get posted on the database:

a:1:{s:20:"first name";s:5:"Jon";}

I need some guidance on how to save only the name that`s getting submitted, in this case is :Jon

```
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'maintenance_forms', 
        array( 
           'form' => $submited['title'],
           'first_name' => serialize( $first_name ),
        )
    );
```

}

Comment: You could always use the Flamingo plugin by the same creator, this saves all CF7 submissions into a table.

Comment: thx Andy, I looked into Flamingo but doesn`t work for me. I need just one row and multiple columns, so far everything is working minus the add stuff (a:1:{s:20:"first name";s:5:"Jon";})

Comment: No problem. I think wordpress kind of hashes the JSON data and spits it out like you see, I'm not sure of the way around this but I know there is a way to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, manage to fix it.

instead of using: 'first_name' => serialize( $first_name ),
i switch to:  $first_name = array ('First name'=> $submited['posted_data']['associatename']);